# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/chill/KryoBase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I am writing a simple spark-cassandra program in java with datastax cassandra but getting below exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/twitter/chill/KryoBase   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.chill.KryoBase

*pom.xml*

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
        <artifactId>dse-spark-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
                <artifactId>dse-java-driver-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

*App.java*

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkJavaFirst")
                    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");     
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);  
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraJavaRDD =  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc).
                    cassandraTable("my_keyspace","my_table" ).
                    select("my_column");
```

Program fails at  `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add com.twitter_chill_2.9.2_Version jar to your existing pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved as I removed the exclusion of

```
 <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>  
  <artifactId>dse-java-driver-core</artifactId>
```